# Angular Posting to .net Web API

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to execute a POST from my angular application to a .net Web API instance but the server returns `null`.

**server**

```
    [HttpPost] 
    public string callBcknd([FromBody]string body)
    {
        try
        {
            Log.Info(string.Format("{0}", body));

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return "error";
        }
    }
}
```

**angular** *note that I am using HttpClient instead of Http.. not sure if this is also the problem

```
callServer(){
    var test = { "name": "John" }
    let data = JSON.stringify(test);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders(); 
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.appService.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/WebApI/callBcknd', 
                          test, 
                          {headers: headers})
  .subscribe(data => {console.log(data);}}}
```

**config**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new {action = "GET", id = RouteParameter.Optional}
            );
        }
    }
```

With above setting, I don't gen any 404 server error in client side(by checking chrome's console) but it returns null in backend. But as I tried with Postman, it sends values properly with the same url. If I don't include [FromBody] inside of method in backend, I get an 404 server error in client side. Furthermore, messages says "NO HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI". Similar question to this seems solving the problem by having [FromBody] but I still get a null... I also suspected maybe my web config file(not the one in above) should contain some headers, so when I added some headers like content type to be json and etc then I get 500 server error in client side. At this point i am really confused and not sure what to proceed.

**UPDATE1**

Following server code returns the message but I am still getting the body as null.. no errors have been observed

```
[HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Callbcknd([FromBody] string body)
        {
            try
            {
                Log.Info(string.Format("called with data {0}", body));

                return Ok(new { Message = "It worked!" });
            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return base.Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: How does this even compile? Your c# method returns type `string` and the only return statement is in the `catch` block. This code should not compile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see multiple reasons why you would get unexpected errors and null values in your code:

1. (error) Your .net method `callBcknd` should not even compile as it can only return something if there is an Exception.
2. (error) You should send json when sending data to your api controller the message body and the api controller method should accept an complex object and **not a primitive type** like `string`/`int`/`bool` etc.
3. (warning) Your angular service should expose functionality and return either observables or promises that the component can then subscribe to. Do not expose the `HttpClient` directly.
4. (warning) Your web api should return interface `IHttpActionResult` instead of the type directly. Then you can use the built in methods like Ok and Content and BadRequest to return status information along with data. See also [Action Results in Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results)
5. (suggestion) Use `Route` and `RoutePrefix` as attributes instead of relying on the route config. This is more flexible and will allow you to also specify parameters to be included in the URL which will make for a more RESTful design. See also [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)
6. (suggestion) Add [CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.htm) to resolve between camel and pascal casing between your front end and backend. See also [Serialization using ContractResolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm)

---

This is a good example of how make calls to a Web API and how to structure your code.

*Note that these code samples only show the relevant parts that were added or modified*

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // add this to ensure that casing is converted between camel case (front end) and pascal case (c#/backend)
        var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

**ApiModel.cs**

```
public class ApiModel {
    public string Content {get;set;}
}
```

**WebApIController.cs**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/WebApI")]
public class WebApIController : ApiController {

    [HttpPost] 
    [Route("callBcknd")]
    public IHttpActionResult CallBcknd([FromBody] ApiModel body)
    {
        try
        {
            Log.Info(string.Format("{0}", body.Content));
            return Ok(new {Message = "It worked!"});
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // example of how to return error with content. I would not recommend actually returning the exception details to the client in a production setting
            return base.Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

**application.service.ts**

```
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){}

callServer(data: {content: string}) : Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:3000/api/WebApI/callBcknd', data);
}
```

**application.component.ts**

```
constructor(private myService: MyService){}

onDoSomething(){
    this.myService.callServer({content: 'This is what I have sent'})
        .subscribe(data => console.log("Succeeded, result = " + data), (err)=> console.error("Failed! " + err));
}
```

---

Notice the following:

1. `ApiModel` represents the incoming object in the request. The angular call then sends `{content: 'This is what I have sent'}` which mirrors this type.
2. `IHttpActionResult` is the response type for your Web API method
3. You can return different types along with status information in the method `CallBcknd`
4. `Route` and `RoutePrefix` were added to give more control over the uri path.
5. The angular component and service have been split into 2 methods, the service returns an observable and the component calls the service methods and subcribes to the returning observable. When you extend this example you want to replace `any` with defined expected results using interfaces and the same is true for any incoming parameters you want to send.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in client side, my original code just works fine sending data. I tried with JSON and verified the Request payload and status code returns OK. Problem is that backend catches error once this JSON arrives and body returns null. Thanks for your suggestion, I will keep that in mind after solving this specific problem.

Comment: @ZlatkoLoa - You need to figure out what the error is on the server. Post the Exception details once you have them. Also status 404 is route not found, you probably do not have everything as I have it above. Status 500 is unhandled exception in your code.

Comment: I get an error HttpErrorResponse{headers: HttpHeaders, status : 500}

Comment: Again, you need to figure out the exception on the server. Debug your server side code or log your Exception so you can read the message, stack trace, and the type. The code I provided above actually returns the entire exception so you can debug on the client side.

Comment: @ZlatkoLoa - See my point #2 above. You should not take primitive types as parameters when using FromBody. Use a complex type like I did in my sample and define it **outside** of another class (**do not nest it, there is no reason to**).

Comment: @ZlatkoLoa - What is wrong with from body? Just do not send a string by itself without using a model for it? If you want to send primitives and nothing else then use the URL. I have no idea what you mean by `I essentially have a set of array that I want to send.`

Comment: For example, I have an array like [ ["1"], ["2"], ["3"], ["4"] ] that I retrieve from some web-service in client side. I was going to grab this array and put it into body in the post. I see I can get JSON data from client to server with the model, but how does this work in this case?

Comment: @ZlatkoLoa - that is an array of single valued arrays with a string value? Is that really what you are getting or is it an array of strings? I am asking because whatever it is you want to send you also need to create a matching model in c#. If you are not sure exactly what you are sending then there is a problem because you can't model it. You would have to do something in c# like dynamic or jsonresponse but what is the point of that because you can't do anything with it (trying to guess at manipulating an unknown structure is pointless).

Comment: @ZlatkoLoa - Taking my code as the example: Change `public string Content {get;set;}` in the model to `public string[][] Content {get;set;}` and then update the data you are sending from angular to `{content: yourArrayOfStringArraysHere}`

Comment: I really appreciate your concerns, but I do have other function that takes conversion from string to json after retrieving the data, and those data don't really need to have any name for my application. I just need to store them in order, later to my local db. I currently removed model, and just have [FromBody] string body in backend. I used toString to convert those arrays to pure string, so i just have 1,2,3,4 . Is it possible to send these data to backend ? With current setting, I get 414 Unsupported Meda Type error. Please refer to post for more details of error

Comment: oops, didn't see your reply. Ill check

Comment: Thanks Igor, I receive all values I want now. Last question to clarify, so If I want to send these kind of data, do I always have to use FromBody along with modelling class?

Comment: @ZlatkoLoa - for complex data this is the best way to send it, using modeling classes. You can also include data in the URL but due to url limitations and types of data it is usually better to stick to primitive types like numbers or simple strings.

Comment: but did I have to use FromBody and a model in my case?

Comment: @ZlatkoLoa - yes because you have a multi dimensional array. If it were a one dimensional array of simple types you could use the URL. In this case though what you have working now is exactly what you need.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a comprehensive post

Answer (score 2):

A Tipical call to a API from "Angular"

```
update(data: string): Observable<IResponse> {
    console.log(data);
    let url = '...';
    let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers })

    return this._http.post(url, data, options)
        .map((res: any) => {
            return res.json();
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);

}
```

The code in API

```
[HttpPost] 
public string callBcknd([FromBody]string body)
{
   try
   {
      Log.Info(string.Format("{0}", body));
      //You must return something
      return "Post Realized";
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      return "error";
   }
}

//I like call async


[HttpPost] 

public async Task<IActionResult>callBcknd([FromBody]string body)
{
   try
   {
      Log.Info(string.Format("{0}", body));
      //await "some action"
      //You can return OK("success") or an object
      return Ok(new { success = true, description = "callback sucesfully" });;
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
            //You can return OK("error") or an object
      return Ok(new { success = false, description = ex.InnerException });;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why post twice? You could have edited your previous answer and added any extra info you wanted to.

Comment: @Eliseo what does second method do?

Comment: If you use a dbs and LINQ several methods use Async, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/index.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the IResult interface (it's NOT c #, it's an own interface that I regularly use)

Comment: ah, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I add a tipical call from Angular

Comment: look "map" in the observable, and "option"

Comment: IActionResult is a interface from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you're posting would look something like

```
{"body":{// something here }}
```

Whereas your controller expects:

`"valuehere"` (which is a valid json for string).

You need to change the c# code to have a model for your DTO:

```
public class PostedObject{
 public object Data {get;set;}
}

  [HttpPost] 
    public string callBcknd([FromBody]PostedObject body)
    {
    // do things

}
```

Comment: I will try tomorrow but I still face with the same problem when I just try to send a string like 'data'

Comment: @ZlatkoLoa that is because by default i suppose `HttpClient` in ng serializes everything as json.

Comment: would it make difference if i use Http tho?

Comment: @ZlatkoLoa No. your problem really is in the c# side. i will see if i can craft the code that can post raw strings for you, but this is quite rarely done these days - purely because it is EASIER to post proper models than it is to post strings like you are trying to.